# Eliminate tuples with reverse relation and no primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert all the relations based on the question below. I have got as far, to get all the relations from A to C (as per the question below). But as for I get, I am also getting the records getting "C friends with A". As far as I understand the question statement "No duplicate friendships", I have to insert friendship as A to C and not vice-versa. Either I understand the problem wrong, or I can't get the desired result.
 So, when I try to insert into the table all the values I've got, my result is wrong. Some persons have friends that are more than desired, by a value of 2.

The structure of the tables is as follows:

```
Friend ( ID1, ID2 )
```

The student with ID1 is friends with the student with ID2. Friendship is mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Friend table, so is (456, 123).

(No primary key)
The situation I am trying to solve is:

"For all cases where A is friends with B, and B is friends with C, add a new friendship for the pair A and C. Do not add duplicate friendships, friendships that already exist, or friendships with oneself."

I have been trying to solve this problem for 2 days now. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

----My SQL query-----

```
select B.ID1 as ID1,B.ID3 as ID2
from (select A.ID1 as ID1,A.ID2 as ID2,A.ID3 as ID3,F3.ID2 as ID4
from (select F1.ID1 as ID1,F1.ID2 as ID2,F2.ID2 as ID3
from Friend F1 join Friend F2
on F1.ID2=F2.ID1
where F1.ID1<>F2.ID2) A join Friend F3
on A.ID3=F3.ID1) B
where B.ID1<>B.ID4
group by  B.ID1,B.ID3
```

Comment: . . Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Please share the SQL you've already tried that is giving incorrect results.

Comment: These are just questions online. I'm trying to solve them to sharpen my skills. But, some are really tedious to solve !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume (for the examples) that the friend table contains these rows.

```
ID1 ID2
--- ---
 a   b
 a   c
 b   a
 b   c
 b   d
 c   b
```

First, start with identifying the 'full friend' tuples from the friend table, with a query like this:

```
SELECT fa.ID1
     , fa.ID2
  FROM friend fa
  JOIN friend fb
    ON fb.ID1 = fa.ID2
   AND fb.ID2 = fa.ID1

fa.ID1 fa.ID2
------ ------
  a      b
  b      a
  b      c
  c      b
```

This result shows us that a is friends with b, and b is friends with c. The `(a,c)` and `(b,d)` rows are omitted because there is no inverse, `(c,a)` or  `(d,b)`.

For the time being, we'll refer to this set as "`ft`" (friend tuples). Now we can write a query against that set (ft), to get all the "a->b->c" and "c->b->a" friend pairs.

```
SELECT fx.ID1
     , fy.ID2
  FROM ft fx
  JOIN ft fy
    ON fy.ID1 = fx.ID2 
   AND fy.ID2 <> fx.ID1

fx.ID1 fy.ID2
------ ------
  a      c
  c      a
```

But, we need to be sure that we don't duplicate any rows that are already in the friend table, so we could use a NOT IN or a NOT EXISTS predicate, or we can use an anti-join pattern, to eliminate rows that match a row already in the friend table.

```
SELECT fx.ID1
     , fy.ID2
  FROM ft fx
  JOIN ft fy
    ON fy.ID1 = fx.ID2 
   AND fy.ID2 <> fx.ID1
  -- eliminate rows that match
  LEFT
  JOIN friend fe
    ON fe.ID1 = fx.ID1
   AND fe.ID2 = fy.ID2
 WHERE fe.ID1 IS NULL

fx.ID1 fy.ID2
------ ------
  c      a
```

Now, we can replace the references to `ft` with the query (as an inline view) that produces the set:

```
SELECT fx.ID1
     , fy.ID2
  FROM ( SELECT fa.ID1
              , fa.ID2
           FROM friend fa
           JOIN friend fb
             ON fb.ID1 = fa.ID2
            AND fb.ID2 = fa.ID1
       ) fx
  JOIN ( SELECT fc.ID1
              , fc.ID2
           FROM friend fc
           JOIN friend fd
             ON fd.ID1 = fc.ID2
            AND fd.ID2 = fc.ID1
       ) fy
    ON fy.ID1 = fx.ID2 
   AND fy.ID2 <> fx.ID1
  -- eliminate rows that match
  LEFT
  JOIN friend fe
    ON fe.ID1 = fx.ID1
   AND fe.ID2 = fy.ID2
 WHERE fe.ID1 IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY fx.ID1
     , fy.ID2
```

(I'm thinking as long as we are guaranteed that (ID1,ID2) is unique, that this query won't generate any duplicates. And I'm thinking that this query will generate only the matches specified, and not any extra matches. Some additional test cases would be in order to confirm. If the query does produce any duplicates, then adding a `GROUP BY fx.ID1, fy.ID2` to the query would eliminate them.)

Finally, to put those rows into the friend table, precede the query with:

```
INSERT INTO friend (ID1,ID2)
```

---

**UPDATE**

The result we want returned really depends on how a "friendship" is represented.

I was assuming that "friend" pair was represented in the `friend` table by the existence of two tuples: both `(a,b)` and (b,a) have to exist. (A friendship is formed when "a friends b", and "b friends a).

If only one of the rows exists, it's not a real friendship, only a halfway friendship.

I ran several test cases. It's kind of tedious working through them. I expanded the query by adding an ORDER BY to get the rows back in a deterministic order, and adding additional columns in the SELECT list, to verify the "path" (shared friend). I commented out the WHERE clause, so I could see all the potential friends.

I did find that I needed to add a `GROUP BY` to eliminate duplicates. We can derive the `a-c` friendship from two or more shared friends e.g. `b` and `r`.  Both `a-b + b-c` and `a-r + r-c` result in `a-c`.

This is the final query I tested. It's essentially equivalent to the previous, except for the addition of the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT fx.ID1
     , fy.ID2
 --  , fx.ID1>fy.ID2 AS d
 --  , fx.ID1 AS x1
 --  , fx.ID2 As x2
 --  , fy.ID1 AS y1
 --  , fy.ID2 As y2
 --  , fe.ID1 AS e1
 --  , fe.ID2 AS e2
  FROM ( SELECT fa.ID1
              , fa.ID2
              , fa.ID1>fa.ID2 AS d
           FROM friend fa
           JOIN friend fb
             ON fb.ID1 = fa.ID2
            AND fb.ID2 = fa.ID1
       -- ORDER
       --    BY LEAST(fa.ID1,fa.ID2)
       --     , GREATEST(fa.ID1,fa.ID2)
       --     , fa.ID1>fa.ID2
       ) fx
  JOIN ( SELECT fc.ID1
              , fc.ID2
           FROM friend fc
           JOIN friend fd
             ON fd.ID1 = fc.ID2
            AND fd.ID2 = fc.ID1
       -- ORDER
       --    BY LEAST(fc.ID1,fc.ID2)
       --     , GREATEST(fc.ID1,fc.ID2)
       --     , fc.ID1>fc.ID2
       ) fy
    ON fy.ID1 = fx.ID2 
   AND fy.ID2 <> fx.ID1
  -- eliminate rows that match existing row
  LEFT
  JOIN friend fe
    ON fe.ID1 = fx.ID1
   AND fe.ID2 = fy.ID2
 WHERE fe.ID1 IS NULL
 GROUP
    BY fx.ID1
     , fy.ID2
 ORDER
    BY LEAST(fx.ID1,fy.ID2)
     , GREATEST(fx.ID1,fy.ID2)
     , fx.ID1>fy.ID2
```

---

If a full friendship is represented by the existence of just one tuple "(a,b)" implies "(b,a)", then the query would need to be changed.

The inline view query for `fx` and `fy` would need to be expanded to return the "missing" inverse tuples... if (a,b) is in the friend table, our query needs to return both (a,b) and (b,a). We'd accomplish that by doing a UNION ALL operation between two identical queries, with just the order of the columns in the SELECT list reversed. (Here, we could actually make use of UNION instead of UNION ALL to eliminate any duplicates.) The inline view query for `fx` and `fy` would be something like:

```
SELECT fa.ID1, fa.ID2 FROM ...
 UNION ALL
SELECT fa.ID2, fa.ID1 FROM ...
```

The check to eliminate matching rows in the friend table would also need to be changed (we'd want to eliminate both (a,b) and (b,a) from the resultset if we found an existing (a,b) or (b,a) row)

```
ON ( fe.ID1 = fx.ID1 AND fe.ID2 = fy.ID2 )
OR ( fe.ID1 = fy.ID2 AND fe.ID2 = fx.ID1 )
```

And the SELECT list and GROUP BY would need to be changed to eliminate the "extra" inverse tuple. We could use an expression like in the ORDER BY

```
SELECT LEAST(fx.ID1,fy.ID2) AS ID1
     , GREATEST(fx.ID1,fy.ID2) AS ID2
       ...
 GROUP
    BY LEAST(fx.ID1,fy.ID2)
     , GREATEST(fx.ID1,fy.ID2)
```

Comment: Huge thanks for such a detailed answer. But unfortunately, this is not giving the desired result. Instead of 2 more values as I was getting, this is giving 1 more value for the number of friends for 3 persons. I still am trying to figure out where this query goes wrong. I will get back with a more detailed answer, sorry for my limitation of better explanation right now !

Comment: @Rijul: The result really depends on how a "friendship" is represented. I was assuming that "friend" pair was represented in the friend table by the existence of two tuples: both `(A,B)` and `(B,A)` have to exist. (A friendship is formed when A "friends" B, and B "friends" A). If only one of the rows exists, it's only a halfway friendship.

Comment: This was superb. I had totally missed the possibility of duplicates through two or more relations. This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. I hope you also Liked solving this question, It took my 2 days of trials !

Comment: @Rijul: I initially considered there might be duplicates (always a possibility whenever we join tables), but my first test case didn't reveal any. I just missed how they'd be generated through two (or more) different shared fried (different paths). (I can see the two different paths when I remove the GROUP BY, and have the extra columns.)

Answer (score 2):

Each of the above answers looks cumbersome, to me.  I think there is a simpler way to represent the query.  As stated in above answers, Lets assume that Friend table looks like the following.

```
ID1 ID2
--- ---
 a   b
 a   c
 b   a
 b   c
 b   d
 c   b
```

If we want the case where the friends are reciprocal, we would look for the case where ‘a’ is friends with ‘b’ and ‘b’ is friends with ‘a.’ Such a query should produce the following results.

```
ID1 ID2
--- ---
 a   b
 b   a
 b   c
 c   b
```

The following sql command would cut to the chase quite nicely and identifies the correct tuples.

```
select *
from Friend
where (ID2, ID1) in (select * From Friend)
```

Which produces the following.

```
ID1 ID2
--- ---
 a   b
 b   a
 b   c
 c   b
```

If I want to make the listing once, eliminate the duplicate, simply add an ‘and’ option that would drop one of the potential tuples, say that  ID2 is less than ID1.  The full SQL statement would read as follows.

select *
from Friend
where (ID2, ID1) in (select * From Friend) and
      ID2 < ID1;

And the duplicate is eliminated.

```
ID1 ID2
--- ---
 a   b
 b   c
```