# SQL grouping by value pairs in multiple columns and eliminating identical tuples

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a database table containing flights. (The origin/destinations are in IATA airport codes.)

```
id   origin   destination
1    AMS      BON
2    BON      AMS
3    EIN      GDN
4    GDN      EIN
5    EIN      GDN
6    AMS      AGP
```

I am trying to find the number of the flights between each two airports, irrespective of the direction of the flight. So I am looking for this result:

```
origin    destination    count
AMS       BON            2
EIN       GDN            3
AMS       AGP            1
```

What I have so far is this query:

```
SELECT c.origin, c.destination, count(c.origin) as count FROM 
(
SELECT a.origin as origin, a.destination as destination FROM Flights a 
UNION ALL SELECT b.destination as origin, b.origin as destination FROM Flights b 
) c 
GROUP BY origin, destination;
```

Which gives the following result:

```
origin    destination    count
AMS       BON            2
BON       AMS            2
EIN       GDN            3
GDN       EIN            3
AMS       AGP            1
```

So the problem is that there are duplicate tuples. How do I eliminate those?

It seems similar to this question, but not similar enough I'm afraid.
[Eliminate tuples with reverse relation and no primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409565/eliminate-tuples-with-reverse-relation-and-no-primary-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier approach is to use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
SELECT least(origin, destination) as city1,
       greatest(origin, destination) as city2, count(*) as cnt
FROM Flights f
GROUP BY least(origin, destination), greatest(origin, destination)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sheer brilliance!